# global variable is not modified by function, scope fact

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update a variable value after a selection in a HTML select. In the jQuery function the value is ok, but after that, the value still is the same that before the function:

**Code:**

```
toRet = null;
//var selector = document.getElementById("id_event_type")
//var valorSeleccionado = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
$(document).ready(function(){           
  slc = $('#id_event_type');

  slc.on('change', function(){

    toRet = parseInt(slc.find(":selected").val(), 10);//here is ok!, $(this) same result

   });
    //from here toRet is null                       
   if (toRet == 2){
     var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/accidente.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
   }
  if (toRet == 0){
    var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/obrasMarker.png',   eventSize, eventOffset);
  }
  if (toRet == 1){
    var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/atascoMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
  }

  eventMarkerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(eventPosition,   eventIcon));
  eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
  $( "#visibilityEvents" ).change(function() {
      if ($('#visibilityEvents').is(":checked")) {
          eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(true);
      } else {
          eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
      }
  });
});
```

Here I put the entire HTML:

**Hole HTML:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
        {% block styles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/css/style.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }
            /* Custom container */
            .container-narrow {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 1000px;
            }
            .container-narrow > hr {
                margin: 30px 0;
            }
            .marketing {
                margin: 10px 0;
            }
            .marketing p + h4 {
                margin-top: 28px;
            }
            .errorlist {
                 color:red;
            }
            #map {
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
                /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
                #no-more-tables table,
                #no-more-tables thead,
                #no-more-tables tbody,
                #no-more-tables th,
                #no-more-tables td,
                #no-more-tables tr {
                    display: block;
                }

                /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
                #no-more-tables thead tr {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: -9999px;
                    left: -9999px;
                }

                #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

                #no-more-tables td {
                    /* Behave  like a "row" */
                    border: none;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                    position: relative;
                    padding-left: 50%;
                    white-space: normal;
                    text-align:left;
                }

                #no-more-tables td:before {
                    /* Now like a table header */
                    position: absolute;
                    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
                    top: 6px;
                    left: 6px;
                    width: 45%;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    text-align:left;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }

                /*
                Label the data
                */
                #no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
          }
        </style>
        {% endblock %}
        {% block body %}
        <div  class="container-narrow">
            <div class="masthead">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <li><a href="/logout/">Cerrar sesi&oacute;n</a></li>

                </ul>
                <h3 class="muted">
                    <img src="/static/img/compass4D-logo.png" width="300px" height="143px"/>
                </h3>
            </div>

            <hr>
            {% load widget_tweaks %}
            <div class="row-fluid marketing">
                <div class="span6">
                    <form action="" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Añadir Evento </legend>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Tipo de evento:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    {{ form.event_type }}
                                    {{ form.event_type.errors }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Posici&oacute;n del evento:</label>
                                <div class="controls form-inline">
                                    {% render_field form.lat_position placeholder="Latitude" %}
                                    {% render_field form.lon_position placeholder="Longitude" %}
                                    {{ form.lat_position.errors }}
                                    {{ form.lon_position.errors }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Sentido:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    {{ form.direction }}
                                    {{ form.direction.errors }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Tiempo de expiraci&oacute;n:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
                                       {% render_field form.expiry_time data-format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" %}
                                        <span class="add-on">
                                            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    {{ form.expiry_time.errors }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="add_road_event" type="submit">Añadir evento</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="controls form-inline">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="addMarkerSelected" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Seleccionar posici&oacute;n
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox" style="float:right; margin-top:6px;">
                            <input id="visibilityEvents" type="checkbox"> Visualizar todos los eventos
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid marketing" style="margin-top:25px;">
                <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Lista de eventos activos</legend>
                        {% if road_events|length %}
                        <section id="no-more-tables">
                            <table class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                                <thead class="cf">
                                   <tr>
                                      <th>#</th>
                                      <th>Fecha creación</th>
                                      <th>Evento</th>
                                      <th>Latitud</th>
                                      <th>Longitud</th>
                                      <th>Sentido</th>
                                      <th>Tiempo expiración</th>
                                   </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tbody>
                         {% for event in road_events %}
                                 <tr>
                                     <td data-title="#">
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                        <input id="{{event.id}}" name="{{event.id}}" type="checkbox" >
                                        </label>
                                     </td>
                                     <td data-title="Fecha creación">{{ event.created }}</td>
                                     <td data-title="Evento">{{ event.get_event_type_display }}</td>
                                     <td data-title="Change">{{ event.lat_position }}</td>
                                     <td data-title="Latitud">{{ event.lon_position }}</td>
                                     <td data-title="Sentido">{{ event.get_direction_display }}</td>
                                     <td data-title="Tiempo expiración">{{ event.expiry_time }}</td>
                                 </tr>
                                   {% endfor %}
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </section>
                            <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" style="margin-top:25px;" name="remove_road_event" type="submit">Eliminar eventos</button>
                        {% else %}
                        Actualmente no hay ningun evento activo.
                        {% endif %}
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="span10" >
            <table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#EFFBF8" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" align="center"><b>Zona corredor</b>
                    <th colspan="3" align="center" >Prioridad a bus</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><b>Solicitada</b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Prioridad<br> habilitada
                    </b></td>
                    <td align="center"><b>Activada</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FAAC58">Zona 1 (Avda. Madrid ascendente)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv1"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="1" type="checkbox" />
                                    {% for i in zone %}
                            {% if i.id == 1 %}
                                    {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                             <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                             <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                    {%else%} <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                            <div id="zs1"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#66CC66">Zona 2 (Avda. Madrid
                        descendente)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                    <div id="zv2"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="2" type="checkbox" />
                                 {% for i in zone %}
                                    {% if i.id == 2 %}
                                    {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                                        <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                                        <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                    {%else%} <br/>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                            <div id="zs2"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFF00">Zona 3 (Gran V&iacute;­a  descendente)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv3"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="3" type="checkbox" />
                                    {% for i in zone %}
                                        {% if i.id == 3 %}
                                            {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                                        <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                                        <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                            {%else%} <br/>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                            {%endif%}
                                        {%endif%}
                                    {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zs3"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#58ACFA">Zona 4 (Gran V&iacute;a ascendente)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv4"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                        <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="4" type="checkbox" />
                                {% for i in zone %}
                                {% if i.id == 4 %}
                                {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                        <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                {%else%} <br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zs4"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FAAC58" style="word-wrap:break-word;">Zona 5 (B.Aires-Autopista hasta Rot. Jenaro de la Fuente-Túnel Martínez Garrido)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv5"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="5" type="checkbox" />
                                    {% for i in zone %}
                            {% if i.id == 1 %}
                                    {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                             <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                             <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                    {%else%} <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                            <div id="zs5"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FAAC58">Zona 6 (Rot. Jenaro de la Fuente-Túnel Martínez Garrido hasta B.Aires-Autopista)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv6"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="6" type="checkbox" />
                                    {% for i in zone %}
                            {% if i.id == 1 %}
                                    {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                             <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                             <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                    {%else%} <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                            <div id="zs1"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FAAC58">Zona 7 (Julián Estévez hasta Rot.Jenaro de la Fuente-Túnel Martínez Garrido)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv7"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="7" type="checkbox" />
                                    {% for i in zone %}
                            {% if i.id == 1 %}
                                    {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                             <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                             <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                    {%else%} <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                            <div id="zs7"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FAAC58">Zona 8 ( Rot.Jenaro de la Fuente-Túnel Martínez Garrido hasta Julián Estévez)</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="zv8"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="/pet_****/" method="GET">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                             <input hidden checked name="zone_id" value="8" type="checkbox" />
                                    {% for i in zone %}
                            {% if i.id == 1 %}
                                    {% if i.****_pet == True %}
                             <img width="40px" src="/static/img/check.png"> <br />
                             <input type="submit" value="Deshabilitar"/>
                                    {%else%} <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Habilitar" />
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endif%}
                                {% endfor %}
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                            <div id="zs8"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

            </table>
        </div>


            <legend><br><br> </legend>

      <div class="footer" style="text-align:right;">

        <a href="http://www.ctag.com"><img src="/static/img/CTAG-logo.png" width="200px" height="100px"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.grupoetra.com"><img src="/static/img/****-logo.png" width="116px" height="100px"/></a>
        <a href="http://www.vitrasa.es"><img src="/static/img/vitrasa-logo.png" width="134px" height="100px"/></a>
        <a href="http://hoxe.vigo.org"><img src="/static/img/vigo-logo.png" width="100px" height="100px"/></a>
      </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script type="text/javascript">


    function sync_vitrasa(id){
        $.ajax({
         url: "/vitrasa_state/",
         type:"GET",
         data: {
           id: id,
         },success: function( data ) {
            id="#zv"+id;

             $(id).html(data);

         }
       });

    }

    function sync_pet(id){
        $.ajax({
         url: "/traffic_ligths_state/",
         type:"GET",
         data: {
           id: id,
         },success: function( data ) {
            id="#zs"+id;

             $(id).html(data);

         }
       });

    }
    /*setInterval("sync_vitrasa(1)",2000);
    setInterval("sync_vitrasa(2)",2000);
    setInterval("sync_vitrasa(3)",2000);
    setInterval("sync_vitrasa(4)",2000);

    setInterval("sync_pet(1)",2000);
    setInterval("sync_pet(2)",2000);
    setInterval("sync_pet(3)",2000);
    setInterval("sync_pet(4)",2000);*/




    </script>

        <script src="/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/openLayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                    language: 'pt-BR'
                });
            });

            var options = {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
            ]
            };

            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options);
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
            var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-8.7181,42.2265);
            center.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            map.setCenter(center,14);

            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
            markers.id = "Markers";
            map.addLayer(markers);

            map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
                if ($('#addMarkerSelected').is(":checked")) {
                    var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                    var positionESPG = map.getLonLatFromPixel (e.xy).transform (map.getProjectionObject(), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
                    $('#id_lat_position').val(positionESPG.lat);
                    $('#id_lon_position').val(positionESPG.lon);
                    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(32,32);
                    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
                    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/newMarker.png', size, offset);
                    var markerslayer = map.getLayer('Markers');
                    while(markerslayer.markers.length > 0){
                        markerslayer.removeMarker(markerslayer.markers[0]);
                    }
                    markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position,icon));
                }
            });

            eventPositions = {{road_events_json|safe}};

            if (eventPositions.length > 0) {
                var eventMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Events" );
                eventMarkers.id = "Events";
                map.addLayer(eventMarkers);
                var eventMarkerslayer = map.getLayer('Events');
                for (var i= 0; i < eventPositions.length; i++) {
                    var eventPosition = new OpenLayers.LonLat(eventPositions[i][1],eventPositions[i][0]).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
                    var eventSize = new OpenLayers.Size(24,24);
                    var eventOffset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(eventSize.w/2), -eventSize.h);
                    var toRet = null;
                    //var selector = document.getElementById("id_event_type")
                    //var valorSeleccionado = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
                    $(document).ready(function(){           
                        slc = $('#id_event_type');

                        slc.on('change', function(){


                            toRet = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                            alert(toRet);
                            //window['toRet'] = parseInt(slc.find(":selected").val(), 10);
                        });
                        alert(toRet);
                        if (toRet == 2){

                            var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/accidente.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
                        }
                        if (toRet == 0){

                            var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/obrasMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
                        }

                        if (toRet == 1){

                            var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/atascoMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
                        }

                        //var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/accidente.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
                        eventMarkerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(eventPosition, eventIcon));

                        eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
                        $( "#visibilityEvents" ).change(function() {
                            if ($('#visibilityEvents').is(":checked")) {
                                eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(true);
                            } else {
                                eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }
            }
            $(".olControlAttribution").css("bottom","-1.5em");

        </script>
        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You register the SLC's "change" event to to a function that changes the toRet value, however NOTHING is stopping the document.ready function to continue with it's execution, so until you actually change the value of SLC, you still have NULL, and the function continues with this null value. Either put all of the code  that follows the change handler inside the change handler, or make a callback.

Comment: @Dellirium I agree.

Comment: ok, now you can see the entire HTML, thanks @Dellirium

Comment: You see the value of the global variable will always get some value whenever the 'change' event is triggered on select-box. Try to change the value of the select box and value of the global variable too will change.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are modifying your global variable *toRet* only in case of some particular change/ event whereas you're checking the condition inside document.ready but outside the change function. Try putting the condition inside change function and the value should definitely reflect.

```
    slc.on('change', function(){

        toRet = parseInt(slc.find(":selected").val(), 10);//here is ok!, $(this) same result
        //from here toRet is null  
    if (toRet == 2){
         var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/accidente.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
       }
      if (toRet == 0){
        var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/obrasMarker.png',   eventSize, eventOffset);
      }
      if (toRet == 1){
        var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/atascoMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
      }

eventMarkerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(eventPosition,   eventIcon));
  eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
  $( "#visibilityEvents" ).change(function() {
      if ($('#visibilityEvents').is(":checked")) {
          eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(true);
      } else {
          eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
      }
  });
       });
```

Comment: If I do that, var eventIcon will not exist outside of the function

Comment: Yes in that case put the rest of the code as well inside your change function. It will work. Because there is no way you are going to get the value of eventIcon if your toRet itself is null. And document.ready() will keep executing other subsequent lines unless change handler gets fired. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I have tried that, but now I can not see my icons on the map, thanks